# I can't save records with no duplicates in SQLite

Tags: android, sqlite

I'm trying to save records with no duplicates in SQLite but even UNIQUE() doesn't help.

Here's where i create db and i want cityName to be unique:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase) {
    sqLiteDatabase.execSQL("create table " + tableName + "(" + KEY_ID + "integer primary key autoincrement,"
    + cityName + " text," + cityTemp + " text, " + " UNIQUE(" + cityName +"))");
}
```

And function that stores in DB:

```
public void saveWeather(Response<CurrentWeather> response) {
    contentValues = new ContentValues();
    database = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    contentValues.put(DBHelper.cityName, response.body().getCityName());
    contentValues.put(DBHelper.cityTemp, 
    response.body().getForecastMain().getTemp());
    database.insert(DBHelper.tableName, null, contentValues);
}
```

I expect no duplicates but they are

Comment: @B001ᛦ, no, it's like this: cityName = "New-York", cityTemp = "20.4" -> each row for city

Comment: If you added the UNIQUE attribute later after you first created he table, uninstall the app from the device so the db is deleted and rerun to recreate the db and the table with that attribute.

Comment: Have you recently added the UNIQUE clause? If so did you delete the database (delete the App's data or uninstall the App and then rerun the App)?

Comment: @Alexander that's good. I've added an answer explaining why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You issue was due to how the **onCreate** method runs.

It only runs automatically once for the lifetime of the database. As such any schema changes made to the create SQL will not automatically be applied.

When developing the typical work around is to delete the database or to utilise the onUpgrade method, if it drops the table(s) and recreates them (generally by calling onCreate) . The database can be deleted by deleting/clearing the the Apps data, uninstalling the App, or via Device Explorer.

If you need to keep existing data then it's a little more complicated.

Answer (score 1):

You would have to keep track if the element has been inserted. Upon inserting a new element the ID (model's variable) would be -1. if the element has been inserter the ID would increment by one. That way you would update the table where there is an entry and insert a new entry if you need.

```
if (I.getId() == -1) { //models ID which would be incremented by one once the element is inserted
            database.insert(DBHelper.tableName, null, contentValues);
        } else {  // otherwise, update
            database.update(DBHelper.tableName, contentValues
                   DBHelper.tableName.KEY_ID + " = ?", new String[]{String.valueOf(I.getId())});
        }
```